# Read File then delete the file with node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I am attempting to use nodeJS to do the following:

Start an executable file (executable file then creates a timestamp_Question.txt file), read the created .txt file and return the text to my front end. Accept user input and create a new timestamp_Answer.txt file with a new name containing the user input, and then delete the original txt file.

Everything seems to be working except the deletion of the original file which is getting the following error

> Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'c:\projects\pizzabox\95912_Questi
>   on.txt'
>       at Error (native)

Here are the various segments of my server code:

Starting the .exe file:

```
  startProgram: function(req, res){
    var date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    date = date.replace(/\D/g,'');
    exec('C:/projects/pizzabox/server/webserver/Pizza_page_server.exe', [date], function(err, data) {  
     console.log(err)
    });
    res.send(date)  /// front end needs date value to track file as date is attached to created txtfile
  }
```

Front end requesting the contents of the txt created by the exe:

```
 getDocument: function(req,res){
    console.log('file requested', req.params.dateStamp);
    var directory = 'C:/projects/pizzabox/'
    var fileCode = req.params.dateStamp.toString()
    var fileSuffix = "_Question.txt"
    var file = directory+fileCode+fileSuffix
    console.log('file is', file);


    while(!fs.existsSync(file)){};
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err,data){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('read ', data);
      res.send(data)
    });
```

Front end submitting data to create new timestamp_Answer.txt file and deletion of old timestamp_Question.txt file:

```
  sendValue: function(req,res){
    console.log('got value', req.body.value, " questionNumber ", req.body.questionNumber, "timestamp ", req.body.timestamp);
    fs.appendFile(req.body.timestamp+'_Answer.txt', "Question_Num:"+req.body.questionNumber+"\nAnswer_Val:"+req.body.value, function(err){
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log('file created!');

      fs.unlink(req.body.timestamp+'_Question.txt', function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('question file deleted');
      })
    })
  }
```

Any reason why unlink wouldn't have access to the file? does fs.readFile() not close/exit the file after it completes?

Comment: FYI, this `while(!fs.existsSync(file)){};` is horrible server-side code.  That will "hang" your server so it can do nothing else and can respond to no other requests until that file exists.  It probably also hogs your CPU and who knows what it does to your hard drive?

Comment: Your `fs.unlink()` code references `req.body.timestamp+'_Question.txt'`, but you don't show any other code that uses that filename so it's hard for us to see what could be causing the issue.  You show an `fs.appendFile()` operation, but it references `req.body.timestamp+'_Answer.txt'` which is a different file.

Comment: Also, please don't ever write code that uses `if(err) throw err` inside an asynchonous callback.  It does nothing useful as it just throws asynchronously back into the `fs` module where you can never catch it.  Write real error handlers that send an error response to the current request.

Comment: If you're creating this file when you run `C:/projects/pizzabox/server/webserver/Pizza_page_server.exe`, your server is not waiting for that to complete so subsequent client/server operations may be occurring while that is still running.

Comment: @jfriend00 the fs.unlink() refrence to req.body.timestamp+'_Question.txt' targets the file earlier in the code that is checked for with fs.existsSync(File)  which i saw you don't like either, what would you recommend i use in place of that, as I need the server to be sure that my .exe has created the file so I can read it, without the while loop node was trying to read the file before it was created. as for the fs.appendFile() I am using it to create a new file, the exe after creating the xxx_question.txt then waits for that file to be deleted and reads xxx_answer.txt before it continues

Comment: Just because the file exists does not mean your exe is done writing to it or has closed it.  You have multiple race conditions.  Needs a major redesign.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have at least one race condition here.  Just because `fs.fileExistsSync()` sees that a file exists, does not mean that the .exe is done writing to that file or has closed that file.  So, it's very likely that your `fs.readFile()` gets called while the file is still open by the other process.

You probably want to rethink how all your operations are sequenced.

First off, the design you have now is a single user design. Your server can only ever be used by one single user at a time since you have no way of differentiating requests that are coming from different users.

Second off, you should move to a design that is more purposefully sequential rather than trying to use the existence of a file in the file system as evidence that some previous operation might now be done.

Third, off `while(!fs.existsSync(file)){};` is never used in anything except a one-off script because it halts all processing of any type of request or timer or any event in the server until that file exists.  Further, it probably hogs all the CPU.  It's never used in a multi-user server.

You haven't really described the overall client/server flow you're trying to design or described whether this is a single-user system or intended to eventually be for multiple users so it's hard for us to make suggestions about exactly where to go for an architectural redesign.

You could probably make one simple improvement by not returning the date to the client until your `.exe` is done which hopefully will stop it from requesting its next step until the .exe is done:

```
  startProgram: function(req, res){
    var date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    date = date.replace(/\D/g,'');
    exec('C:/projects/pizzabox/server/webserver/Pizza_page_server.exe', [date], function(err, data) {  
     if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.sendStatus(500);
     } else {
          // don't send this until the .exe is done
          res.send(date)  // front end needs date value to track file as date is attached to created txtfile
     }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I can't wait for the date to be sent back because the .exe persists, I may need to explain it's function better.

> Server starts the .exe passing XXX (XXX is the timestamp)
> .exe creates XXX_Question.txt  
> Server reads XXX_Question.txt and sends the text to the client so the user can respond to the question and send the response back to the server
> Server creates XXX_Answer.txt, and deletes XXX_Question.txt
> .exe reads XXX_Answer.txt and creates a new XXX_Question.txt (XXX is still original value)
> Repeat until .exe stops prompting and generates a HEX file for user to DL

Comment: @AaronManill - OK, your current design does not work - you have a race condition and several other problems.  You need a better way for the exe and your express program to communicate than looping to check the file system.  There are dozens of intraprocess communication methods you can use.  My first question would be why the question generating logic is even in a separate exe in the first place when it could just be in your Express program and things could be a lot simpler.

Comment: @AaronManill - If not, then make your exe a small http server with only local access and have your express program send it requests and get responses.  There appears to be no reason why you need to start a new exe for every date stamp either.  It could just be a little server that processes requests for questions and requests for responding to answers (that don't have to be in the file system or discovered by polling the file system).  Looping the file system for communicating with an external process is a crummy way to communicate.

Comment: The .exe is a firmware building tool, and the question flow is not linear, the .exe ensures the proper flow of questions based on the answers, and outputs an end result in hex which is very challenging to do with javascript, I suppose it may be possible to build the proper question flow in Node and then just send a full answer object to an exe designed to just process all the data at once instead of the .exe guiding the website through the process

Comment: @AaronManill - Or just use a better way to communicate between the programs than looping on the file system.  Use one of the many means for intraprocess communication.  For example, you could send answers on stdio for the exe and receive questions on stdout.